# Design LNK302 with external current boost

Tags: current, switch-mode-power-supply, buck, switching-regulator

I want to use the LNK302, which can work as buck converter. Of course it does not operates similar to buck converters like MC34063 but I tried in many ways to boost the current on the LNK302 with a MOSFET but had no success (tried on simulations only).

Is there a way use the LNK306 output for the input signal of a boost converter?

I tried the direct feedback and the Optocoupler feedback but had no sucess.

It can be a problem with my simulations, if anyone knows a way of making it work, please share a schematic.

[LNK302 Datasheet](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/328/lnk302_304-306-179954.pdf)

Below is an image of my actual schematic trying to adapt what is in the datasheet with boost cricuit (probably very wrong)
[image: My actual schematic trying to adapt what is in the datasheet with boost circuit (probably wrong)]

Comment: You ask about a LNK302, whatever that is, but then give us a link to something called a LNK306 datasheet.  Pick one.  Also, post the circuit *you are actually using*.  Closing until these mandatory clarifications are forthcoming.

Comment: Fixed all the irregularities.

Comment: These switchers are for hi-voltage low-power applications. Why bothering using a part in an application for which it has not been designed for, especially considering the plethora of available part-numbers fitting your needs? In a non-floating application, the switcher source must be grounded and the drain loaded by an inductor. You can see that you need an opto not for isolation but to reverse the FB polarity. If you want to build a simple dc-dc from a 40-V source with the correct way of sensing \$V_{out}\$, check recent part-numbers from semi manufacturers, it will ease your design job : )

Comment: Yeah I know, but I am not going to apply it, I am just trying to make it work to learn and out of curiosity, if I needed to really build a Step-Down I would use the correct IC.